# "Intended for distribution with a new PC" means it is OEM?

Tags: microsoft-office, oem

Just to get it clear.
If i have Office 2013 Home&Business license and on DVD there is label "Intended for distribution with a new PC", than it means i have OEM license, no way [Retail terms apply](https://blogs.office.com/2013/03/06/office-2013-now-transferable/)?

Comment: Similar topic: http://superuser.com/questions/208803/what-does-microsoft-office-2010-oem-installation-mean?rq=1   ........... Refer: http://superuser.com/questions/250908/windows-7-oem-is-opk-use-required and http://superuser.com/questions/972680/what-does-intended-for-distribution-with-a-new-pc-mean-on-an-oem-windows-7-hom/  .. Not directly related, but gives more details on OEM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the wording Microsoft uses when it's an OEM license.